# page block table number of rows

Tags: apex

I created a page block table in visual force. When I open the page, I want 5 empty rows. how can I achieve this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class to wrap your SObject. Then create five empty records of it and put that into the list you want to show in your dataTable

Answer (score 1):

If your table rows are an SObject (such as `Contact`) and you have no other need for a wrapper class create the rows once in your controller e.g.:

```
public Contact[] rows {
    get {
        if (rows == null) {
            rows = new Contact[] {};
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // Could default values here if that made sense
                rows.add(new Contact());
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }
    private set;
}

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rows}" var="row">
...
```